# Rx Extensions: How do I make a subscription dependent on another subscription?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a class that takes an observable in its constructor, then subscribes to it and does some stuff, sets properties etc.  The class itself is observable.

I want to subscribe to my source observable only if someone is subscribed to my class, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
public MyClass : IObservable<MyResult>
{
    private readonly Subject<MyResult> _subject = new Subject<MyResult>();
    private readonly IConnectableObservable<MySource> _source;

    public MyClass(IObservable<MySource> source)
    {
         _source = source
             //All my logic to set properties and such
             //goes here as a side effect, instead of in a subscription...
             .Do(...)
             //I hope that by publishing, side effects will happen only once...
             .Publish();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<MyResult> observer)
    {
        return new CompositeDisposable(
             _source.Subscribe(/* 
                  don't have anything to do here,
                  just subscribing to make sure I'm subscribed to source...
                  (this can't be the right way to do it)
             */),
             _subject.Subscribe(observer));
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE

@Scott: I can see why implementing IObservable would be an anti-pattern. `My Class` needs to consume a single observable, and exposes 3 as properties (originally the most commonly used observable was going to be returned by `MyClass` itself, but I think that having it as a property might be better.

What I'm trying to write is an observable ICommand.  I know some exist, but this is more of a way to learn Rx...

```
public class ObservableCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly ISubject<T> _executeRequests = new Subject<T>();
    private readonly ISubject<T> _canExecuteRequests = new Subject<T>();

    public IObservable<bool> CanExecuteChanges { get; private set; }
    public IObservable<T> CanExecuteRequests { get; private set; }
    public IObservable<T> ExecuteRequests { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCommand(IObservable<bool> canExecute)
    {
        var source = canExecute.DistinctUntilChanged()

        //How do I dispose of subscription later?
        //I have this fear that I'm going to have a chain of references, 
        //and my entire app will never get GC'd!
        var subscription = source.Subscribe(
            o => {
                if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                    CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            });

        CanExecuteChanges = source;

        CanExecuteRequests = _canExecuteRequests.AsObservable();

        ExecuteRequests = _executeRequests.AsObservable();
    }

    #region ICommand Members

    public bool  CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        _canExecuteRequests.OnNext(parameter is T ? (T)parameter : default(T));
    }

    public event EventHandler  CanExecuteChanged;

    public void  Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _executeRequests.OnNext(parameter is T ? (T)parameter : default(T));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I know you are using this as a learning experience. If you get stuck, you might check out the excellent ReactiveUI version of the same thing for some hints. https://github.com/xpaulbettsx/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI.Xaml/ReactiveCommand.cs

Comment: @Anderson: I was actually looking ReactiveUI, but I found I didn't know enough about Rx itself to use it comfortably, looks like a good lib though.

Comment: ah yeah, that makes it tough. To learn the operators themselves more thoroughly, I used RxSandbox... it helped a lot. Hope it helps you: http://mnajder.blogspot.com/2010/03/rxsandbox-v1.html

Comment: Also... you'll notice that ReactiveUI subscribes to the CanExecute right away, rather than delaying until someone subscribes to anything else. It's pretty low cost to operate this way, though I understand the desire.

Answer (score 1):

How about just not `Do`ing or `Publish`ing in the constructor, but rather in the `Subscribe` method?

It should be said, explicitly implementing `IObservable<T>` is something of an Rx anti-pattern.

You can make Subscriptions dependent on other subscribers with `Defer` and `Create`, something like

```
IObservable<MySource> source;
IObservable<MySource> sourceWithSubSideEffect =  Observable.Defer(() =>
{
   // Do something interesting on Subscription
   // ....
   return source;
});
```

Comment: An example would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Understood - can you describe what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: `Defer` is static, not an extention method on `IObservable`. It can only be used like `Observable.Defer()`. `Create` is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared a snipped for you. `MyClass` implements `IObservable<T>` and has also methods of `IObserver<T>` but they are all private. With additional `OnInitialize` and `OnSubscribe` you should be able to do whatever you want on any event you want to response to.

If you want to make this snipped reusable you could define all methods as `partial` as they all return `void`. Then you could create definition to whatever you want.

```
public class MyClass<T> : IObservable<T>
{
    private readonly IObservable<T> m_Source;

    public MyClass(IObservable<T> source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        m_Source = source.Do(OnNext, OnError, OnCompleted);
        OnInitialize();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        OnSubscribe();
        return m_Source.Subscribe(observer);
    }

    private void OnInitialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnInitialize");
    }
    private void OnSubscribe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnSubscribe");
    }
    private void OnNext(T value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnNext: {0}", value);
    }
    private void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnError: {0}", error.Message);
    }
    private void OnCompleted()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted");
    }    
}
```